Examples of non-spatial but Hausdorff locales
Every Hausdorff topological space is sober, hence can be identified with a spatial locale; furthermore, every locally compact Hausdorff topological space is also Hausdorff as a locale.
On the other hand, there seems to be no reason that a Hausdorff locale should have any points at all, let alone be spatial.
What are some interesting examples of non-spatial Hausdorff locales?
(A Hausdorff locale is a locale $X$ such that the diagonal $\Delta : X \to X \times X$ is a closed embedding.)

Since every sublocale of a Hausdorff locale is Hausdorff, in principle it suffices to find a non-spatial sublocale of any Hausdorff locale.
For example, if $K$ is an compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points, then the smallest dense sublocale of $K$ is Hausdorff but has no points.
However, I am more interested in "natural" examples, especially ones where Hausdorff-ness has some extrinsic interpretation related to the construction of the example.

Any complete atomless Boolean algebra is Hausdorff yet has no points. This is just from the identity that for any $a,b$ in a Boolean algebra, $$(a,b)=(a\wedge b,a\wedge b)\vee(a\wedge b,b\wedge\neg a)\vee(a\wedge\neg b,b)$$
and the second two pairs have meets of $0$.
